# CSS Table Cell Padding Having No Effect In FF And IE8

Tags: css

I'm probably missing something terribly obvious but I can't hack my way into the proper layout for my table.  I have some nested tables.  The innermost tables are all class=cell and I want to control the padding for the td elements in these tables.  Here is the CSS:

```css
.cell
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
.cell td
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 24px;
}
```

When I add this to either selection above it has no effect on the table:

```css
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
```

I have no other CSS that affects the td element.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT:  Here is the complete CSS.  It is applied to a set of nested tables.  The outer, containing table is class=outer.  It contains two tables for the left and right columns and in the columns the tables with class=cell are stacked on top of each other:

```
.outer
{
    border: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
    .outer td
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
    .column
{
    border: none;
}
#rightColumn table, #leftColumn table
{
    width: 100%;
}
    .cell
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
    .cell td
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 24px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
.image
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 75px;
}
.messages td
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    text-align: left;
}
h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 350%;
}
h2
{
    text-align: center;
}
th
{
    background-color: #2B60DE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.gray
{
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
.blue
{
    background-color: #2B60DE;
}
.orange
{
    background-color: #FFA500;
}
.green
{
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
.red
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.yellow
{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
.white
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.cell .span2
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.centered
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: can you also show the HTML (rather than describing it), or produce a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: The problem is not in the code posted but in some part that was not included. The padding settings take normal, expected effect when tested with `<table class=cell border><td>foo</table>`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `position: relative;` to the css rules you have. + it would be nice to actually see your html.